# Camel in action filtering using xpath

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

Hi I am learning Camel (using Camel in action). I am on Chapter 2 (page 49). To filter messages from an order

the following code is given:

```
from("jms:xmlOrders").filter(xpath("/order[not(@test)]"))
.process(new Processor() {
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
System.out.println("Received XML order: "
+ exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));
}
});
```

Q1. Is everything in the message an order element? E.g. Order name=motor, order amount=1 or Order name=motor but amount=1?

Q2. How does the @ work? E.g. the @test? What if I wanted to create a filter that would filter out all orders which have order amounts > 1, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code assume that the message from the jms queue "xmlOrders" are xml, or can be converted to xml.

This route apply then a xpath filter on this xml message. You can find on Google a lot of tutorials on xpath : it's a query language for xml fragments. The `/order[not(@test)]` means "an <order/> element without a test attribute". Your query can be, for example, if an order element has a amount attribute : `"/order[@amount > 1]"`

See for example http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp